# What is the difference between the processes listed by `ps` and `ps -A`?

Tags: bash, unix, ps

What is the difference between the processes listed by `ps` and `ps -A` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without the `-A`, ps will only print the processes belonging to the current session. Think of it like "absolutely everything". On a related note `-a` does the same thing, but restricting it to the session-owner (username).

Comment: Why does `ps -a` list different processes than `ps x` for GNU ps?  I would think both would restrict it to the current user.

Comment: According to the man page, `ps -a` does not include [session leaders](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18166/what-are-session-leaders-in-ps), whereas `ps x` does.

Answer (score 1):

The GNU `ps` command suffers from a severe case of multiple personality disorder.  So it is no wonder that its manual page is confusing.  Perhaps a look at the BSD manuals might help.  After all, this question *is* tagged [unix](/questions/tagged/unix).

The operation of BSD `ps` is fairly straightforward when one bears two things in mind:

- Processes are selected for display using two basic filters.  Those filters are *on* by default and command line options turn them *off*.  Plain unadorned `ps` is thus filtered through both.
- BSD syntax goes back a long way.  Although the modern BSDs use `getopt` and the convention of options prefixed by a minus sign, the options and behaviour relevant here are much the same as from 30 years ago.

That behaviour is this:

- The `-a` (historically `a`) option *turns off* all "selector" filtering.

  - The various other command line options specify selectors: `-U` selects by UID, `-t` by controlling terminal name, `-p` selects by process ID, and so forth.  All of these are bypassed by `-a`.
  - If no selectors are explicitly supplied, the *default selector* is to only display processes running with the same effective UID as the user who invoked `ps`.  This default selector is the historic filter that this option turns off.
- The `-x` (historically `x`) option *turns off* the restriction that `ps` only display processes that have a controlling terminal.

Historically, BSD `ps` did not have an `A` option.  But modern BSDs implement an `-A` option, also usable as `A`, for (a degree of) compatibility with the (later) Single UNIX Specification.  `-A` is simply the same as using both `-a` and `-x`: it turns both restrictions off, leaving one with all processes, unfiltered.

OpenBSD and NetBSD document the `-A` option, in NetBSD's case explicitly as `-a -x`.  FreeBSD does not, but a comment in the source code states that it is there as an intentionally undocumented SUSv5 compatibility option.

## Further reading

- [`ps`](http://modman.unixdev.net/?sektion=1&page=ps&manpath=4.2BSD) 1983-04-13.  4.2BSD Manual pages.
- [`ps`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ps.1) OpenBSD Manual pages.
- [`ps`](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?ps) 2009-10-22.  NetBSD Manual pages.
- [`ps`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ps(1)) 2014-08-07.  FreeBSD Manual pages.

Comment: To get the BSD behavior with GNU ps (the default ps in ubuntu), leave off the - in the arguments: `ps a`, `ps x`, `ps ax`, or `ps -A` (that last one you must leave the - on).